# How can I deposit money from my account to a friend's account in another state?

Tags: banking

Can I deposit money from my account to a friend's account who lives in another state?

Comment: Are you referring to another state within the USA, or somewhere else?

Comment: The answer depends on which country or countries you are asking about and possibly currencies too. In the US, there are many ways of doing this, some free, some with a fee, and some that require active participation by your friend, that is, you can’t send a surprise birthday gift.

Comment: More details are needed. Aside from the country... Are you trying to do it directly into his account without his knowledge? What type of account do you have? Can you just hand him a check or cash?

Comment: Is this a real friend? Have you met this friend in real life? Do you know for sure you're not getting involved a scam?

Comment: You might look at whether your bank (or credit union &c) has a "bill pay" service.  Some of these allow you to make payments to individuals: I use mine to pay a friend (who does live in another state) for my share of expenses.  But as others have said, first make sure that this is an actual friend, and not a potential scammer.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend signs up for a PayPal account.

You sign up for a PayPal account.

He sends you a PayPal invoice for the amount.  You pay it.

Bada-bing.

If that's a problem for your friend, that's hard to explain.  He may be a "friend" who is actually a stranger you met on the Internet, or someone engaged in any of a number of possible frauds against you.   It's also likely he is a foreigner, because the procedure above should be *easy as pie* for anyone who is indeed a US citizen with a bank account.  This is when you start hearing really silly things like Western Union or Bitcoin or other dubious methods.

Also, if this is a followup to that stranger sending you a check of some kind, fair warning: that check *will* bounce after a month or two, even though the bank released all the money. Then you must pay all the money back to the bank.  If you've sent it onward to this "friend", you are left holding the bag.  *That's how a scam works*.

Answer (score 1):

Send them a check in the mail.

Comment: Yes.  To his USA mailing address.   That could end up going to the scammer's patsy -- note all those "get a job cashing checks for us" spam ads out there, but then, so could any other method of payment.